# Sorting the latest added in Django 

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to show the 8 most recent scans added by doing this:

```
def index(request):
....
recent_scans = Image.objects.filter(category='Scan').order_by('-date_added')[:8]
...
```

It "works," but it is not literally getting the 8 most recent scans. The order is different compared to the order for the `def scans`. The order is not completely different, it's just that there a few scans misplaced.

What is weird is that it works in this view:

```
def scans(request):
    image_list = Image.objects.filter(category='Scan').order_by('-date_added')
```

Taking out the `[:8]` to see if it'll sort correctly does **NOT** work, though...so I don't know what it wrong. My only guess is that the Image model is connected through a ManytoMany...

I've also tried this:

```
recent_scans = Image.objects.filter(category='Scan').latest('date_added')
```

But it comes with this error:

> Caught TypeError while rendering: 'Image' object is not iterable

Here is my model, btw:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('Cover', 'Cover'),    
    ('Scan', 'Scan'),
    ('Other', 'Other'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    contributor = models.ManyToManyField(Contributor, blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title        
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']
```

I've tried adding 'get_latest_by = "date_added"` to the Meta class in my models, but that did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why it doesn't correctly order by `date_added` even though in my `Issue` model, it does. My only guess is that the database doesn't correctly order by the latest item if it's a `DateField` and not a `DateTimeField`. Weird, because, again, the `Issue` model does the same.

So, I've simply just worked around it by sorting by the `id` and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

`latest()` returns an instance, not a `QuerySet`, as the [django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest) clearly states:

> **latest(field_name=None)**
>
> Returns the latest object in the table, by date, using the field_name provided as the date field.

You could run something like

```
print [i.date_added \
    for i in Image.objects.filter(category='Scan').order_by('-date_added')[:8]]
```

to see what dates the "wrong" results actually have...

Comment: Here's what I get: `[datetime.date(2011, 5, 23), datetime.date(2011, 5, 23), datetime.date(2011, 5, 23), datetime.date(2011, 5, 23), datetime.date(2011, 5, 23), datetime.date(2011, 5, 23), datetime.date(2011, 5, 23), datetime.date(2011, 5, 23)]`  I really have no idea what is going on. Actually, I've evoking Python queries and it's showing different entries every time when I sort by date_added. Is it because the date_added are all the same? This is a DateTime field too and not just a Date field.

Comment: Another weird thing...I checked my PostgreSQL tables and they are showing up in order there...

Comment: Actually the model you posted above shows a `DateField` instead of a `DateTimeField`...

Comment: Well, I don't think this should affect the ordering  either way because another model I have is a `Datefield` and it sorts correctly.